# Is there any pro wrestling dataset available ?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, sports, database

Is there any open data-set available for pro wrestling? Something like matches info, ppv data or even start ratings for matches helps. Wrestling promotions could be wwe/wwf, njpw, roh or impact/tna wrestling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [Internet Wrestling Database](http://www.profightdb.com/) is a free resource of professional wrestling information.

http://www.profightdb.com/tos.html

Comment: Thanks. I was actually hoping for something like readily downloadable CSVs. But I guess one can scrape data from this website, right?  "Terms and Conditions
The Internet Wrestling Database is a free resource of professional wrestling information.  Our intent is to make available on the Internet information (data and images) pertaining to this subject.  This information is provided and distributed freely."

Comment: That was my take on the terms as well.  =)